# Windows 10: disable welcome experience on boot after update

Tags: windows, windows-10, auto-login

How can I disable the following screen after a system update? I need the system to immediately login to the account I have set to auto-login.

[image]

I'm sure this has already been answered but I can't seem to figure out the right keywords / official nomenclature to describe this screen. I thought it was the "welcome experience" but [apparently that's something else](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/76252-turn-off-windows-welcome-experience-windows-10-a.html)(the "Show me the windows welcome experience after updates" toggle does not affect this). Any help much appreciated.

**Edit:** Found [this article](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/08/09/how-to-disable-get-even-more-out-of-windows-on-windows-10/) but it appears to be out of date. All notifications in Settings > Notifications & Actions are already disabled and there is no "UserProfileEngagement" item in regedit's Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion.

Comment: Not sure how you can disable it during windows, but you can disable it in NTLite while slipstreaming Windows, but that would technically mean reinstalling windows.

Comment: Press "Let's go". It will come back otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Deal with it, close it and move on. It should not come back again - it does not come back on my 3 computers here.

It is not removable in Settings, Apps.

> You can see the Windows Feature Experience Pack listed as one of the
> Features on Demand for Windows 10 and Windows Server. This list also
> includes Internet Explorer, Notepad, the DirectX Configuration
> Database, Paint, PowerShell ISe, Quick Assist, the Print Management
> Console, and more. The Windows Feature Experience Pack, listed as
> available on Windows 10 version 2004 and later, "includes features
> critical to Windows functionality." **Microsoft advises users not to
> remove this collection of Windows client shell components**, which is
> 44.15MB in size

From  https://www.tenforums.com/windows-10-news/158219-what-windows-10-windows-feature-experience-pack.html

Comment: close it how? "skip for now"?

Comment: The question seems to imply an unattended system. This answer fails to address it. In addition, the screen posted, when hitting "let's go" prompts for user credentials and/or setting up a Microsoft live account if I recall. Also not possible on a headless or unattended system. And "NO" it actually does come back after certain updates.

Comment: Windows workstation is normally a user-run system (other than Kiosks).  I dealt with in on my production systems and have not seen it since. I see it on some feature updates on my Insider machine. I have expressed my displeasure in the Insider Feedback Hub and I am not the only one.

Comment: It is indeed an unattended system that's set to boot up and run a certain app on a regular schedule "permanently", so I need to guarantee that this welcome experience will not occur again, even if I have to go against Microsoft's official recommendation. Thanks anyway.